# sqlite tutorial

Tags: c, sqlite

Is there any good tutorials/books on how to use sqlite with C??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the book: [The Definitive Guide to SQLite](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596730) (1st Edn, 2006) by Mike Owens.  It is a very good book.

There is also a [second edition](http://www.betterworldbooks.com/the-definitive-guide-to-sqlite-id-9781430232254.aspx) available from multiple sources, including Amazon: [The Definitive Guide to SQLite (Expert's Voice in Open Source)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430232250) (2nd Edn, 2010) by
Grant Allen and Mike Owens.

Comment: I prefer "Using SQLite" (O'Reilly, 2010). It's a great resource for C developers and database designers.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, right at their website:  http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html